# What is the difference between rm -r and rm?

Tags: terminal

Can rm be used for directories as well? I know that the -r means recursively but in terms of functionality, how are the 2 commands different?

Comment: They're different in the way you describe, `-r` adds recursive directory traversal.  `rm` by itself will remove a file.  If you attempt to remove a non-empty directory with it (or perhaps with `rmdir`), it will return an error.  That's what the recursive flag is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `-r`, `rm` only deletes the named files (and not directories).  With `-r`, as you say, it's recursive and will delete both files and directories, both in and under the named directories.